# Uso de Diretivas para criação de quase tudo

Tags: framework, angular

Trabalhei há alguns dias num projeto onde utilizávamos o angular 1.*.
O caso é que, cada tabela que criávamos em tela, ou qualquer elemento com dados e uma certa complexidade, era criado uma diretiva para tal, além do controller, etc.

Minha pergunta é: Devemos criar tantos arquivos assim apenas para colocar uma tabela em tela?
Não sei se isso é um padrão mas se for, não concordo muito com ele...

Será que não estamos confundindo as coisas e trazendo responsabilidades do back para o front e acabamos assim por duplicá-las? Respondo por que disso.
Essa aplicação que comentei foi desenvolvida de C# no template MVC. Neste template você já tem as configurações de rota. Para que fazer o mesmo no angular, ou seja lá qual for o framework .js.

A impressão que dá é que temos muito mais trabalho ao usar o framework que tem um ciclo de vida menor que a tecnologia pai (js, etc)  e me faz pensar se vale a penas usarmos todos estes recursos dipostos e padrões impostos.

> Não estou falando mal do framework e sim tentando entender se este
>   padrão que comento realmente existe e o por que dele existir.

Comment: Eu acho que utilizando o Angular com um Restful Api, como o Web Api 2 você teria mais proveito do recurso, acho que com MVC acaba ficando redundante mesmo, mas não sei como é a arquitetura do projeto e porque decidiram fazer assim.

Comment: Faz sentido @WilliamCézar. Então na verdade, se for usar a plataforma .net, faria mais sentido criar uma app sem o template MVC, é isso?

Comment: Para mim sim, faz mais sentido usar a Web Api, o MVC possui muitas dependência que você não precisaria utilizando o Angular, talvez seja ate interessante utilizar o .net core

Comment: Mas daí, estamos falando de template certo? O caso do .net core não sei. Por que usaria ele específicamente?